# obect doesn't get recognized java

Tags: java, object

I'm currently stuck with a problem. I intilized the obj player a few lines before `Player player = players.get(0);` , yet in the next lines it says player hasn't been resolved. Is there a simple way to fix this?

`players.get(0)` isn't empty, i tested it with `System.out.println`.

```
GameStoreProvider.getInstance().addObserver(gameState -> {
    List<Player> players = gameState.getPlayers();
    Player player = players.get(0);
});

for(int i = 1; i<300; i++) {
    var action = new RandomCardAction(player);
    try {
        GameStoreProvider.sendAction(action);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: hint: variable scope

Comment: just move the for-loop inside the `addObserver` method

Answer (score 1):

The code:

```
gameState -> {
        List<Player> players = gameState.getPlayers();
        Player player = players.get(0);
    }
```

defines a anonymous function, which has it is inner scope. What is defined inside 
is not visibile to the outer scope.

You can move the variable definition above in the main scope like this:

```
final Player player;
gameState -> {
        List<Player> players = gameState.getPlayers();
        player = players.get(0);
    }
```

to solve the compilation problem or you can do all the work releated to the `player` inside the inner scope(as suggested by @Arcturus) by moving the loop inside.

Comment: You can't do that, as variables used in lambda must be a `final` one

Comment: @Alex Whatever. It can be also a global variable.

Comment: have you tried? It can't compiled. It complains that "The final local variable player cannot be assigned. It must be blank and not using a compound assignment"

Answer (score 1):

Its because the player lives inside the lambda function. If you give `addObserver` a lambda, you give `addObserver` control when to call this function. It can be directly, but it can also be over 10s. Meanwhile, your other code can still be executed, even if the `addObserver` is not even done yet. This means that player can be `null` when the code arrives at your for loop

You might want to migrate the second piece inside the lambda as well:

```
GameStoreProvider.getInstance().addObserver(gameState -> {
    List<Player> players = gameState.getPlayers();
    Player player = players.get(0);

    for(int i = 1; i<300; i++) {
    var action = new RandomCardAction(player);
    try {
        GameStoreProvider.sendAction(action);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The player defined in the lambda expression is a local variable not visible outside the lambda. Check the line

```
var action = new RandomCardAction(player);
```

player should be null there.